# Summing a vector's elements with do-while loop in C++

Tags: c++, do-while

I am trying to add the elements of a vector with the condition that the sum of the elements is greater than(>) a certain number. This has to be done sequentially, so at the end I get several "merged" elements satisfying the above condition

For example, if the MINSUM = 10  and v_1 = 4, v_2= 7 , then v_1+v_2 = 11 > 10 , quit the loop  - If not, then add also v_3 and check the condition again. Here is what I am doing, but does not work well

```
vector < float >values_;        //this vector holds the real number I want to add
float sum_ = 0;
     ////////loop inside the vector 
for (unsigned t = 0; t < values_.size(); t++) {
        //        //////first , take the first element of the vector
        float cont_ = values_[t];
        //             /////and add the next value
        float cont_next = values_[t + 1];
        /////some stupid boolean
        bool check_point = false;
        sum_two_bins = cont_;
        //         ////////and now loop        
        do {
                sum_ += cont_next;
                t++;
                check_point = true;
                break;
        }
        while (sum_ < MINENTRIES);
        if (check_point)
                cout << " at the end, is the sum ok more than MINENTRIES? "
                    << sum_ << "  " << t << endl;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code to make the world a better place to live in.

Comment: `float cont_next = values_[t+1];` will crash for the last element...
Uhh and there is another `t++`...

Comment: Why on earth are you adding underscores to the end of all your variables?

Comment: And `float cont_next = values_[t + 1]` will yield undefined behavior on the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Nop...this is why I do ask for help ;-)

Comment: I take back the comment about the `while`.  Your code formatting made this confusing for me.

Comment: sure ;-) But can you provide a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<float> values;
float sum = 0.0f;
for(const auto& value : values)
{
    if(sum += value > MINENTRIES)
          break;
}

cout << " at the end, is the sum ok more than MINENTRIES? " << sum << "  " << t << endl;
```

C++98

```
std::vector<float> values;
float sum = 0.0f;
for(std::vector<float>::iterator it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it)
{
    if(sum += *it > MINENTRIES)
          break;
}

cout << " at the end, is the sum ok more than MINENTRIES? " << sum << "  " << t << endl;
```

Comment: - Error: illegal label name auto& value

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.6.2 , but actually, your loop will exit once the >MINENTRIES is met - What I want it to sum the 1rst+2nd, if >MINENTRIES, then add the 3rd+4rth if <MINENTRIES then 3rd+4rth+5th then check the condition again and then add the 6th+7th etc etc - So a recursive check for all elements, starting from two every time, check if < add the next, check ....

Comment: You probably need to enable C++11 compilation. Though it is rather trivial to convert to C++98. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

There is an STL algorithm to perform this task: `std::accumulate` within the `<numeric>` header.

```
std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

Comment: But that won't break early when the sum reaches MINSUM and won't tell you how far it got (you could use a custom function object to do that though)